# Responsive data grid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, datatables

Is there any JS data grid component, free, which has a responsive layout?

I tried DataTables and jqGrid but I couldn't find anything on them about responsive layout.

Visitors of my website should have a good experience with data grid based visualizations on mobile devices, but the most common components (at least free) don't offer this kind of feature.

Comment: I bumped you up from a -1 to 0 because this is a good question. Maybe someone didn't like the word "free." Sometimes you just have to pay to play!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the general search I made for responsiveness in the grids, we have very few options. The ideal scenario is reduce the number of logical columns in the table. In order to make it more responsive you can use the jqGrid and mention the load size based on the window size $( window ).resize().

You can also check the below option
http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a good roundup of responsive data grids out there at the moment here:
http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/


Personally I think the ideal solution is still not quite there.  I don't like any mobile app to have both vertical and horizontal scrolling. I also think in most cases you don't want to drop columns.  I also would prefer that the "markup" for a grid does not require you to make any considerations/pointers for the grid to be displayed on a mobile device, but I think this is probably impossible for a decent UX.

It is debatable whether there will ever be a one-fits-all solution for this problem.  I would have to say ideally you would create different solutions for different circumstances.  So for instance if you have a grid of e-mails on your desktop, on mobile you would probably expect them to display in the sort of format you see in any of the well-known mobile mail apps.  But that might not apply to a list of items which have a lot more columns.  Also there are "collapsible rows" to consider.

Saying that, I think *most* datagrids in simple admin applications could be made responsive, but the solution isn't there yet.